# Get DataGridRow depending on Mouse position?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have made a silverlight application, that contains some datagrid.
I am using some `Drop` event on them.

The thing is, I want to select the Row on the `DataGrid`, that match with the position of the mouse, when I drop my item.

The problem is : When I drag an item from my desk to the app, I can't access to all the `MouseEvent`. And also, when I drag an item, it does not select the row, that is on a mouse over.

So, I can't identify the good row to update...

Is this possible to make what I want?

Matches the position where I drop my item, and a row on the `DataGrid`.

For now, I can get the drop item position like this :

```
Point position = e.GetPosition(this.datagrid);
```

I tried also getting the good row with this :

```
var hits = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(position, this.datagrid);
```

But it always return 0 results.

I kown we can have `SelectedItem` on a `DataGrid`, but this doesn't help, as when I drag an item, the `DataGrid` `SelectedItem` will not change until the item is dropped...

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show a bit more code please? I tried it on my side in a sample Silverlight application and the `VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates` returned all the elements.